# Android first app Hello world logcat errors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm just using Ray wanderlich tutorial to create my first ever android app - a basic hello world. The app is successfully launched on the emulator and the text is displayed as expected. however i don;t like the errors in the logcat. Highly appreciate if someone helps me to identify why logcat behaving unexpectedly.

```
07-16 18:03:02.661    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:03:03.021    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:03:07.221    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
07-16 18:04:10.802    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 500K, 21% free 2434K/3056K, paused 192ms, total 203ms
07-16 18:04:10.832    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
07-16 18:04:11.072    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:04:11.232    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:04:15.312    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
07-16 18:05:18.643    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
07-16 18:05:18.833    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:05:18.993    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:05:23.263    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
07-16 18:05:27.533    1247-1287/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
07-16 18:05:27.753    1247-1287/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Done.
07-16 18:05:27.763    1247-1287/system_process D/ConnectivityService﹕ Setting timer for 720seconds
07-16 18:06:10.304    1247-1247/system_process D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 415K, 11% free 4481K/5028K, paused 235ms, total 260ms
07-16 18:06:26.674    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
07-16 18:06:26.824    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:06:27.064    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:06:31.314    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
07-16 18:07:34.675    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
07-16 18:07:34.765    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:07:34.875    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:07:39.065    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
07-16 18:08:42.446    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Error writing to device
    java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
     Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
            at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:101)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
            at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:567)
            at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
            at btx.run(SourceFile:130)
07-16 18:08:42.486    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Socket closed
07-16 18:08:42.576    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
07-16 18:08:46.696    1353-1477/com.google.android.gms.wearable D/WearableConn﹕ Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
```

Comment: these errors aren't related with your app. Actually it is Google Play Services which is not being able to connect your device with some web server.

Comment: Yeah... you can't look at an error in logcat and assume you've done something wrong. Let the errors flow. It's easier that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a command prompt and type the command netstat and check whether port 5601 is open. if it is there then open another command prompt and type the following command
telnet localhost 5554

once connected

type

```
redir add tcp:5601:6000
```

and 
quit

Check if it helps..